# jQuery 1.6.2, jquery 1.10.2 and IE 8.0 - jQuery null or not an object

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, conflict

That's rather strange combination, but anyway:
1. Two jQuery work together fine in Chrome, Firefox and so on, using noConflict().
2. Bug was found in IE8: jquery 1.6.2 raises the error, which is shown in IE debugger (F12) as  **jquery null or not an object**

problem code (highlighted by yellow color) is:

```
{if(jQuery.inArray(curID,curArr)==-1)
```

what am I doing wrong and how to fix it ?

Comment: You shouldn't be loading two jQuery libraries. There's no need to.

Answer (score 1):

You have no reason to have two jQuery libraries, there will be conflicts. If you need to upgrade try using JQuery migrate.